# Using pixel colors for artificial neural networks

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I want to try and make a program that can identify pictures. Since I'm using the pixel colors as input, should I have 3 inputs for each pixel in the image? (RGB values)

Comment: I'm sorry you what now?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm using it for an artificial neural network. The input nodes is what I'm asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color images are normally defined by at least three channels: R(red), G(green) and B(blue). You may also have alpha and all sorts of other channels. So yes, for one pixel you will have 3 inputs.

You have to clarify what exactly "identify pictures" entails.

Answer (score 0):

"Identify pictures" is a very vague term.

You might want to take a look at something like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for handling image data. Within that library, the **Mat** structure provides very transparent pixel storage and access.

As far as semantics go, the function doing the "identification" would ideally accept an **image object** as an input, as opposed to image channels.

Comment: I've looked into it, I use SDL_image atm. I just wanted to know if i need an input for each color value for each pixel (meaning 3 values per pixel)